# How to pass a coordinate to inference data

Tags: pymc3, pymc, arviz, bambi

I've been skimming through Arviz documentation and came across 8 school inference data.

```
import arviz as az
idata = az.load_arviz_data("centered_eight")
```

Inference data object also includes `school` coordinate. How can I do that with my `bambi` models? I always have a dimension column that looks like `..._dim_...`.
Thanks!

[image]